# Apply, Merge, Colnames, Data.frame

Tags: r

Here's my data, wrapped in a data.frame,

```
rt5.5 <- c(0, 7, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1) #LC trace % area
rt6.3 <- c(0, 16, 12, 20, 16, 20, 13, 15) #LC trace % area
rt8.4 <- c(0, 26, 55, 56, 63, 61, 70, 70) #LC trace % area
rt9.4 <- c(88, 42, 20, 11, 8, 6, 5, 3) #LC trace % area
rt22.7 <- c(8, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6) #LC trace % area
LCtraces <- data.frame(rt5.5, rt6.3, rt8.4, rt9.4,rt22.7,
                       row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))
total.area <- apply(LCtraces,1, sum)
LCtraces <-  merge(LCtraces,total.area, by="row.names")
colnames(LCtraces) [7] <- "Total Area"
rm(rt5.5, rt6.3, rt8.4, rt9.4, rt22.7, total.area) #tidy
```

When I built the data.frame I wanted to add up the totals across the rows: for this I used the apply function, then I merged the resulting vector with the data.frame using row.names.  I then put the column name that I wanted.

What I've done works but lacks elegance, can anyone suggest any improvements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rowSums` and `transform`:

```
LCtraces <- transform(LCtraces, total.area = rowSums(LCtraces))
```

Equivalently, using `within`:

```
LCtraces <- within(LCtraces, "Total Area" <- rowSums(LCtraces))
```

Comment: Answered in seconds, thanks.  Pity I can't give you two ticks.